# Sort loop with query in the link

Tags: query, rewrite-rules, sort

I want to add some buttons that will sort the post by name asc/desc etc.
I want to use query in the link like this

```
http://domain.tld/?orderby=name&order=asc
```

Is this safe to use?

Are there rewrite rules i can use to change orderby=name to order-name and order=asc to ascending?

Answer (score 0):

You could use rewrite rules but doing it the way you've put should be fine.

It's safe so long as you sanitize the query string.

Using `add_query_arg()` you can add a query to the end of your current URL, like this:

```
   $link = add_query_arg( 'orderby', 'name', get_permalink() );
```

You can then, for example, apply it to a button:

```
   <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">Sort by name</a>
```

So now, when you click that link it will add 'orderby=name' to your URL. You could do this manually but `add_query_arg()` makes it easier and cleaner and there's also `remove_query_arg()` to help you too.

So now that we've changed the URL we now need do the ordering. I'm going to assume you're using the standard homepage query which is the most recent 10 posts and we're going to use `pre_get_posts` to complete the task. If you're not familiar with this then you should read up on it and see how you can exploit it, rather than creating secondary queries (if that is indeed what you're currently doing).

```
function wpse_142352_orderby( $query ) {

    // Don't do this in the admin and ONLY for the main loop
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    // Only on the frontpage
    if ( is_home() ) {

        // Safely get the orderby value
        $orderby = sanitize_key( $_GET['orderby'] );

        // If orderby is set then do it
        if (isset($orderby) {
              $query->set( 'orderby', $orderby );
              return;
        }
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_142352_orderby', 1 );
```

That means now, instead of showing the 10 most recent posts, it will show the first (or last depending on if order = ASC or DESC) 10 in alphabetical order.

Hope that helps.

Comment: in your code i don't see where i could set the order. What i want is to have buttons for orderby=name&order=asc, orderby=name&order=desc, orderby=date&order=asc, orderby=date&order=desc. I don't want to touch the loop.

Comment: Just follow the first two code blocks then and add multiple arguments to add_query_arg() - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg

Comment: I can't figure it out how to get both orderby and order, but even then the output is the same: http://domain.tld/?orderby=name&order=asc. I wanted the query to be rewritten to  http://domain.tld/name/asc; but never mind that, you said it's safe to use http://domain.tld/?orderby=name&order=asc as long as i sanitize the query string, can you show me how i can do that for http://domain.tld/?orderby=name&order=asc? Thanks for the help so far.